# how to Get every char after this :

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, split, substring

This is my input: `"29 : installed : com.digikala;33 : deleted : com.digikala "` 
I want to get everything after 2nd `:` . output should be something like this: `com.digikala`

```
    string test ="29 : installed : com.digikala;33 : deleted : com.digikala "
var list= test.Split(';').ToList();
   list.substring(?)
```

And How can get this `installed` too?
With many thanks.

Comment: Use `split` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to split the string:

```
string test = "29 : installed : com.digikala"; 
var s = test.Split(new char[] { ':' });

string first = s[0]
string second = s[1]
string third = s[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
string test ="29 : installed : com.digikala"
test.substring(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string but make sure to account for the white space in between the split strings. You can do this using `Trim()`

```
string test = "29 : installed : com.digikala";
string[] splits = test.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(splits[2].Trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

I am just writing to Console below. But you can change it accordingly.

```
string test ="29 : installed : com.digikala;33 : deleted : com.digikala";
var list= test.Split(';').ToList();
foreach(string s in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s.Split(':')[1]); //this gives you installed or deleted
   Console.WriteLine(s.Split(':')[2]); //this gives you com.digikala
}
```

Take a look at the LinqPad capture [image]

Comment: I have the code and also a picture to show it. Why Downvote?